# ¿Como Copiar y Pegar Texto Seleccionado en un ListBox con click secundario del Mouse?

Tags: c#

Alguien sabe como copiar y pegar el texto seleccionado dentro de un ListBox utilizando el evento de click secundario del mouse, hasta el momento solo lo he realizado con un TextBox.
Solo Tengo el Evento del Click secundario pero no tengo idea como seleccionar el texto.

```
private void button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        /*Si oprime el boton secundario*/
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: no alcanza con copiar el texte del item seleccionado?

Answer (score 1):

Para copiar el texto seleccionado del ListBox al portapapeles de windows puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
private void button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    /*Si oprime el boton secundario*/
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
         ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip(); //creas un contextMenuStrip para seleccionar la opción de copiar


            menu.Items.Add("COPIAR", default(Image), btnCMSCopiar).Name = "copiar"; //botón del menu para copiar que llama al evento btnCMSCopiar
            menu.Items.Add("CANCELAR").Name = "cancelar"; //botón del menú para cancelar


            menu.Show(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position); // haces visible el menú en la posición de ratón

    }
}

private void btnCMSCopiar(object sender, EventArgs e) //evento que se desencadena al pulsar la opción de copiar
    {

       Clipboard.SetDataObject(ListBox.SelectedItem.toString(), true); //copias en el portapapeles de windows el item seleccionado en el listBox

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este codigo haciendo click con el botón derecho copias el texto del elemento seleccionado ; Al hacer click sobre el listBox, la opción de copiar se abre sobre el elemento seleccionado, aunque hagas clik sobre cualquier otro elemento del listBox.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ejemplo0
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            }

        ContextMenuStrip nu = new ContextMenuStrip();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            nu.Items.Add("Copiar");
            nu.Opened += new EventHandler(nu_opened);
            nu.Click += new EventHandler(nu_Copiar);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            listBox1.ContextMenuStrip = nu;
            }

        void nu_Copiar(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            Clipboard.SetText(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }

        void nu_opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            nu.Show(MousePosition.X,this.Location.Y + listBox1.Location.Y + nu.Height +Convert.ToInt32((listBox1.SelectedIndex+1)* listBox1.ItemHeight));
            }
        }
    }
```

Con este otro código puedes copiar parte de un elemento cualquiera. Crea y superpone un listBox (listBox1) y un richTextBox (richTextbox1), con el mismo tamaño, para que se alternen de acuerdo al uso que corresponda.

Haciendo click sobre el listBox, emerge el richTextBox, en el que ves el texto de los elementos, y el texto del elemento seleccionado, seguidamente al seleccionar texto de un elemento y soltar el botón luego de seleccionar ( KeyUp ), se abre el ContextMenuStrip con la opción de copiar ; Y al copiar alguna seleccion, emerge de nuevo el listBox seleccionado el elemento sobre el que se hizo el ultimo click.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ejemplo0
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();

    string listBoxString = "";
    ContextMenuStrip nu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    bool firstsight = true;
    bool selecting = false;
    bool contextMenuStripOpening = false;
    bool bringingListBox1ToFromToFront = false;
    int lastStartIndex = 0;


    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int selected = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
      int startSel = 0;
      richTextBox1.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(richTextBox1_TextChanged);
      richTextBox1.Text = "";

      if (firstsight)
        {
        richTextBox1.ContextMenuStrip = nu;
        firstsight = false;
        }

      for (int c = 0; c < listBox1.Items.Count; c++)
        {
        if (c == selected)
          startSel = richTextBox1.Text.ToString().Length;
        richTextBox1.Text += listBox1.Items[c] + Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();
        }

      listBoxString = richTextBox1.Text;
      richTextBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(richTextBox1_TextChanged);
      richTextBox1.BringToFront();
      richTextBox1.Focus();
      richTextBox1.SelectionStart = startSel;
      lastStartIndex = startSel;
      SendKeys.Send("+{DOWN}");
      SendKeys.Send("+{LEFT}");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Controls.Add(listBox1);
      this.Size = new Size(360, 310);

      listBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      listBox1.Size = new Size(200, 150);
      listBox1.Location = new Point(80, 80);
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM1");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM2");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM3");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM4");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM5");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM6");
      listBox1.Items.Add("ITEM7");

      listBox1.Location = new Point(80, 80);

      listBox1.Click += new EventHandler(listBox1_Click);
      richTextBox1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(richTextBox1_MouseUp);
      richTextBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(richTextBox1_MouseDown);
      this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
      richTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      richTextBox1.Size = new Size(200, 150);
      richTextBox1.Location = new Point(80, 80);
      richTextBox1.SendToBack();
      nu.Items.Add("Copiar");
      nu.Click += new EventHandler(nu_Copiar);
      nu.Opened += new EventHandler(nu_opened);
      nu.Visible = false;
      listBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
      listBox1.BringToFront();
    }


    private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int lastSelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

      richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

      selecting = true;

      int c_ = 0;

      string part = richTextBox1.Text.ToString().Remove(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);

       for(int c__ = 0; c__ < part.Length; c__++)
        if (part[c__] == '\n')
          c_++;

      listBox1.SelectedIndex = c_;
      selecting = false;

      richTextBox1.SelectionLength = lastSelectionLength;

      if (contextMenuStripOpening && !bringingListBox1ToFromToFront)
        open_contextMenuStrip();

    }


    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      richTextBox1.Text = listBoxString;
    }

    private void nu_opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
        {
        nu.Visible = false;
        return;
        }
      else
        nu.Visible = true;

      open_contextMenuStrip();
    }

    void open_contextMenuStrip()
    {
      contextMenuStripOpening = true;

      if (selecting)
        return;

      nu.Show(MousePosition.X, this.Location.Y + listBox1.Location.Y + nu.Height + Convert.ToInt32((listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) * listBox1.ItemHeight));

      nu.Visible = false;

      contextMenuStripOpening = false;

    }


    private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText != "")
      {
        if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 1 && richTextBox1.SelectedText.ToString().Contains("\n"))
          richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectedText.ToString().Remove(richTextBox1.SelectedText.ToString().IndexOf("\n")).Length;
         nu.Show(MousePosition.X, this.Location.Y + listBox1.Location.Y + nu.Height + Convert.ToInt32((listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) * listBox1.ItemHeight));
      }
      else if (richTextBox1.SelectedText == "" && bringingListBox1ToFromToFront)
         nu_CerrarContextMenuStrip();
      else if (richTextBox1.SelectedText == "")
        bringingListBox1ToFromToFront = true;
      else
        bringingListBox1ToFromToFront = false;
    }

    private void nu_CerrarContextMenuStrip()
    {

      if (selecting)
        return;

      if (richTextBox1.SelectedText == "" && !bringingListBox1ToFromToFront)
        return;


      listBox1.BringToFront();
      listBox1.Focus();

      Thread.Sleep(40);

      bringingListBox1ToFromToFront = false;
    }

    void nu_Copiar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
        return;

      Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
      listBox1.BringToFront();
      listBox1.Focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede copiar el ListBox al portapapeles con esta sencilla función:

```
public void CopyListBoxToClipboard(ListBox list)
{
    // Pasamos los elementos del ListBox a un array
    string[] items = list.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

    // Copiamos la lista al portapapeles (separados los elementos por un salto de línea)
    Clipboard.SetText(String.Join("\r\n", items));
}
```

> Recuerde que debe incluir la librería `System.Linq`

Y puede pegar del portapapeles al ListBox con esta otra función:

```
public void PasteInListBox(ListBox list)
{
    string list = Clipboard.GetText();
    string[] items = list.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        list.Items.Add(item.Trim());
    }
}
```

Entonces solo tendría que llamar a dicha función:

```
private void button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    /*Si oprime el boton secundario*/
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        this.CopyListBoxToClipboard(this.listbox1);

        // O sino

        this.PasteInListBox(this.listbox1);
    }
}
```